# allow get user location notification doesn't show up swift ios 8

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, core-location

I am trying to write route from user's location to the destination point.

I add in `info.plist` these lines [image]

And this is my code to write the route:

```
class ItinerarioVC: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

@IBOutlet var steps: UITextView!
@IBOutlet var distanceLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var destinationLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var theMapView: MKMapView!

let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
var annotationTitle: NSString!
var annotationSubheading:Int!

var routeDetails: MKRoute!
var allSteps: NSString!
var destinationCoordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
  }

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

    //setup our location manager
    self.locationManager.delegate = self
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    self.locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

    //setup our map view
    theMapView.showsUserLocation = true

    var destinationPlacemark:MKPlacemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: destinationCoordinate, addressDictionary: nil)
    var source:MKMapItem = MKMapItem.mapItemForCurrentLocation()

    var destination:MKMapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: destinationPlacemark)
    var directionRequest:MKDirectionsRequest = MKDirectionsRequest()

    directionRequest.setSource(source)
    directionRequest.setDestination(destination)
    directionRequest.transportType = MKDirectionsTransportType.Automobile
    directionRequest.requestsAlternateRoutes = true

    var directions:MKDirections = MKDirections(request: directionRequest)
    directions.calculateDirectionsWithCompletionHandler({
        (response: MKDirectionsResponse!, error: NSError?) in
        if error != nil{
            println("Error for getting direction: \(error)")
        }
        if response != nil{

            // find the best way
            var temp:MKRoute = response.routes.first as MKRoute
            var min = response.routes.first?.distance
            for (var i=1; i < response.routes.count; i++)
            {
                if response.routes[i].distance < min
                {min = response.routes[i].distance
                    temp = response.routes[i] as MKRoute}
            }
            self.routeDetails = temp
            self.theMapView.addOverlay(self.routeDetails.polyline)
            if (self.annotationSubheading != 0)
            {
                if self.annotationSubheading == 20
                {
                    self.destinationLabel.text = eventPub.title as String
                }
                else
                {
                    self.destinationLabel.text = companyWithServicePub.name as String
                }
                self.destinationLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
            }

            self.distanceLabel.text = NSString(format:"%0.1f KM", self.routeDetails.distance/1000)

            setRegionToFit(self.theMapView)
            self.allSteps = ""

            for (var i = 0; i < self.routeDetails.steps.count; i++)
            {
                var step:MKRouteStep = self.routeDetails.steps[i] as MKRouteStep;
                var newStep:NSString = step.instructions
                self.allSteps = self.allSteps.stringByAppendingString( "\(i+1). ")
                self.allSteps = self.allSteps.stringByAppendingString(newStep)
                self.allSteps = self.allSteps.stringByAppendingString("\n\n");
                self.steps.text = self.allSteps;
            }
        }
        else{
            println("No response")
        }
        println(error?.description)
    })

    // show destination on map

    var destannotation = CustomPointAnnotation()
    destannotation.title = annotationTitle
    destannotation.coordinate = destinationCoordinate
    destannotation.subheading = annotationSubheading
    self.theMapView.addAnnotation(destannotation)
 }

func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, rendererForOverlay overlay: MKOverlay!) -> MKOverlayRenderer! {
    if overlay is MKPolyline {
        var polylineRenderer = MKPolylineRenderer(overlay: overlay)
        polylineRenderer.strokeColor = UIColor.blueColor()
        polylineRenderer.lineWidth = 4
        return polylineRenderer
        }
    return nil
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {
    CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(manager.location, completionHandler: { (placemarks,error) -> Void in
        if (error != nil) {
            println("Error to get user location: " + error.localizedDescription)
            return
        }

        if placemarks.count > 0 {
            let pm = placemarks[0] as CLPlacemark

        }
        else {println("Error with data")}
    })
}


func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didFailWithError error: NSError!) {
    println("Error: with user location" + error.localizedDescription)
    self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
}
}
```

I tried to run this on my iphone ios 8.1.2 , the allow "your app" to access your location while you user the app message doesn't show up, and I have this error, only if I first manually go to settings/privacy/ to set allow geolocation for my app then I don't have any error:

```
Error for getting direction: Optional(Error Domain=MKLocationErrorDomain Code=0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (MKLocationErrorDomain error 0.)"     UserInfo=0x17086ee40 {NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Active localization to allow (null) to determine your location})
No response
Optional("Error Domain=MKLocationErrorDomain Code=0 \"The operation couldn’t be completed. (MKLocationErrorDomain error 0.)\" UserInfo=0x17086ee40 {NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Active localization to allow (null) to determine your location}")
Error: with user locationThe operation couldn’t be completed. (kCLErrorDomain error 1.)
```

Can somebody tell me what is wrong in my code?
And I would like to know how can I get my app continues find user location even if it with the first attempt doesn't achieve it?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried reseting your simulator? Or uninstalling and rebuilding your app?

Comment: I'm running this on my iphone not on the simulator.

Comment: Try to delete the app and build it again.

Comment: I tried but it still doesn't show up.

Comment: Delete one of the line `requestWhenInUseAuthorization` or `requestAlwaysAuthorization`! Use only one!

Comment: I delete requestWhenInUseAuthorization, seems it works for showing the message. Thank you